# how to find the maximum number

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

$f(z)$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n$.

1. Show that $f$ assumes each value of $\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}$ exactly $n$ times except for a finite number of exceptions.
2. What is the maximum number?

I tried
$f(z)=a$ where $a \in\CC$ $(1)$.
Let $a_1$, $a_2$,$\ldots$,$a_n$ be the roots of the equation $(1)$,
and let
$b_1$,$b_2$,$\ldots$,$b_{n-1}$ be the roots of $f'(z)$
these are fixed for every $a \in \CC$.
If $a_1$ is a multiple root of order 2 or more then $b_i=a_1$ for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.

What do I do next?

Comment: What do you mean by what is the maximum number? The maximum number of what?

Comment: maximum number a€C such that f(z)-a=0 has multiple root/roots.

Comment: Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/90543 for how to use MathJax to format math on this site

Comment: Show that f assumes each value of *what* exactly n times?

Comment: n times means  f(z)=a for n values of z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like you solved 1 and you're just asking about 2 right?

For 2, note that $f(z)-a$ has multiple roots if and only if it has a common root with $(f(z)-a)'=f'(z)$. In other words, using the notation from your question, $f(z)-a$ has multiple roots if and only if $f(b_i)-a=0$ for some $i$ if and only if for some $i$, $f(b_i)=a$. Thus the largest $a$ such that $f(z)-a$ has multiple roots is the $f(b_i)$ with the largest norm.

Answer (score 0):

I tried,
integration **f'(z)** we get **f(z)+c**.
for multiple solution of **f(z)+c** and **f'(z)**
gcd(**f(z)+c** ,**f'(z)**) must be not equal to 1.
gcd(**f(z)+c** ,**f'(z)**) can be (n-1)! type.
so   ***c*** can take almost (n-1)! values.
that is ***f(z)***=***a(=-*c*)*** which has multiple root can be at most (n-1)! values of ***a***.

Comment: am I right  in this case?